# How to Switch to OTA Provisioning option in Wireless toolkit J2ME?

Tags: java-me, emulation, midp, ota, java-wireless-toolkit

I am new to J2ME and now I have to solve one J2ME project.
Below is my login form I don't know what to do with that but it is giving me the error **"javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: TCP open"**. After searching on the google I got some hint that we have to run the code on **"OTA Provisioning option "**.
Now I don't know how to do that. I have **"Version 2.5.2 for CLDC"** of WTK. Can anybody suggest me on that?

```
package model;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import javax.microedition.rms.RecordEnumeration;
import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore;
import view.Dialogs;

public class Login {
    public static RecordStore rs;    // Record store
    static final String REC_STORE = "db_Login"; // Name of record store
    static  RecordEnumeration re;
    private String login,password;
    private int c;
    public static String s1,s2,s3;

    public Login()
    {
         if(LoginSrv.st1.equals("Invalid") && LoginSrv.st2.equals("User"))
       { 
           System.out.println("Im from Invalid User");
           new Dialogs();
       }

       else
       {
        login = LoginSrv.st1;
        password = LoginSrv.st2;
        c= LoginSrv.it1;
        saveRecord();
       }
    }
    public Login(String log,String pas, String ctr)
    {
        s1 = log;
        s2 = pas;
        s3 = ctr;

    }
    public void saveRecord()
    {
        try
        {
                rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore(REC_STORE, true );
                re = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baosdata = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream daosdata = new DataOutputStream(baosdata);
                daosdata.writeUTF(login);
                daosdata.writeUTF(password);
                daosdata.writeInt(c);
                byte[] record = baosdata.toByteArray();
                rs.addRecord(record, 0, record.length);
                System.out.println("Login record added");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Im from model Login craete record"+e);

        }

    }
    public static Login getRecord()
    {

        try
        {
            rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore(REC_STORE, true );
            re = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
        if(re.hasNextElement())
        {
           byte data[] = rs.getRecord(re.nextRecordId());
           ByteArrayInputStream strmBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
           DataInputStream strmDataType = new DataInputStream(strmBytes);
           String log = strmDataType.readUTF();
           String pass = strmDataType.readUTF();
           String counter = strmDataType.readUTF();
           return(new Login(log,pass,counter));
        }
        return null;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Im from model Login loadRecord"+e);
            return null;
        }    

    }

}
```

-----------------------LoginSrv code ---------------------------------------

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package model;

import com.sun.lwuit.Dialog;
import controller.AppConstants;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author sandipp
 */
public class LoginSrv {
    private ServCon srv;
    public static String st1,st2,log,pas;
    public static int it1;

    public LoginSrv(String s1, String s2)
    {
        log = s1;
        pas = s2;
        it1=0;
        try
        {
           ByteArrayOutputStream baosdata = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           DataOutputStream daosdata = new DataOutputStream(baosdata);

           daosdata.writeUTF(s1);
           daosdata.writeUTF(s2);
           srv = new  ServCon(new AppConstants().str1,null,baosdata.toByteArray(),false,false,null);
           ByteArrayOutputStream obj = (ByteArrayOutputStream)srv.startTransfer();
           byte[] record = obj.toByteArray();
           ByteArrayInputStream instr = new ByteArrayInputStream(record);
           DataInputStream indat = new DataInputStream(instr);

            if(srv.getRc() == 200)
            {
                String su = indat.readUTF();
                if(su.equals("successfull"))
                {
                 st1 =indat.readUTF();
                 st2 =indat.readUTF();
                }
                else
                {
                 Dialog.show("Error",su , null,Dialog.TYPE_INFO,null,5000);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Dialog.show("Error",srv.getRc() + " " + srv.getRm(), null,Dialog.TYPE_INFO,null,5000);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Im from LoginSrv constructor:"+e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have seen that exception when there is no upstream connection available. Can you share the code for the `LoginSrv` class?

Comment: @Steve O'Connor  please check the Loginsrv code tell me if you want anything more